# Create table with jQuery - append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have on page div:

```
<div id="here_table"></div>
```

and in jquery:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    $('#here_table').append( 'result' +  i );
}
```

this generating for me:

```
<div id="here_table">
    result1 result2 result3 etc
</div>
```

I would like receive this in table:

```
<div id="here_table">
    <table>
          <tr><td>result1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>result2</td></tr>
          <tr><td>result3</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I doing:

```
$('#here_table').append(  '<table>' );

 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    $('#here_table').append( '<tr><td>' + 'result' +  i + '</td></tr>' );
}

 $('#here_table').append(  '</table>' );
```

but this generate for me:

```
<div id="here_table">
    <table> </table> !!!!!!!!!!
          <tr><td>result1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>result2</td></tr>
          <tr><td>result3</td></tr>
</div>
```

Why? how can i make this correctly?

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/n7cyE/

Answer (score 210, accepted):

This line:

```
$('#here_table').append( '<tr><td>' + 'result' +  i + '</td></tr>' );
```

Appends to the `div#here_table` not the new `table`.

There are several approaches:

```
/* Note that the whole content variable is just a string */
var content = "<table>"
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    content += '<tr><td>' + 'result ' +  i + '</td></tr>';
}
content += "</table>"

$('#here_table').append(content);
```

But, with the above approach it is less manageable to add styles and do stuff dynamically with `<table>`.

But how about this one, it does what you expect nearly great:

```
var table = $('<table>').addClass('foo');
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    var row = $('<tr>').addClass('bar').text('result ' + i);
    table.append(row);
}

$('#here_table').append(table);
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: for the second example, you need a td inside your tr and then do .text on the td. Also when created html element with jquery you only need the opening tag. $('<table>') works great.

Comment: For the jquery example, you can use smaller tag names, like `$('<table/>')` instead of `$('<table></table>)`, and `$('<tr/>')` instead of `$('<tr></tr>)`, etc.

Answer (score 43):

You need to append the `tr` inside the `table` so I updated your selector inside your loop and removed the closing `table` because it is not necessary.

```
$('#here_table').append(  '<table />' );

 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    $('#here_table table').append( '<tr><td>' + 'result' +  i + '</td></tr>' );
}
```

The main problem was that you were appending the `tr` to the `div` here_table.

**Edit:** *Here is a JavaScript version if performance is a concern. Using document fragment will not cause a reflow for every iteration of the loop*

```
var doc = document;

var fragment = doc.createDocumentFragment();

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var tr = doc.createElement("tr");

    var td = doc.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = "content";

    tr.appendChild(td);

    //does not trigger reflow
    fragment.appendChild(tr);
}

var table = doc.createElement("table");

table.appendChild(fragment);

doc.getElementById("here_table").appendChild(table);
```

Comment: great answer! Thank you! I used your JavaScript version to display a dynamic table in App Inventor http://puravidaapps.com/table.php

Comment: Should not use innerHTML to pass plain text

Comment: You should use `element.textContent` for plain text.

Comment: @ChazyChaz fair comment but this was posted 9 years ago when IE 9 was new and `textContent` was not supported below IE 9. It's also not the focus of the answer. Commenting posts that are 10 years old can be tricky with the technology landscape changing so quickly.

Comment: @Craig yeah, you're absolutely right, the purpose of the comment was just to make sure people coming across these old answers know this. I know this well cuz I was once lazy and skipped the documentation and instead relied in old answers.

Answer (score 22):

When you use `append`, jQuery expects it to be well-formed HTML (plain text counts).  `append` is not like doing `+=`.

You need to make the table first, then append it.

```
var $table = $('<table/>');
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    $table.append( '<tr><td>' + 'result' +  i + '</td></tr>' );
}
$('#here_table').append($table);
```

Comment: +1 The best approach here - shows that jQuery actually works on DOM elements, not on raw HTML.

Answer (score 14):

Or do it this way to use ALL jQuery. The each can loop through any data be it DOM elements or an array/object.

```
var data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'];
var numCols = 1;           


$.each(data, function(i) {
  if(!(i%numCols)) tRow = $('<tr>');

  tCell = $('<td>').html(data[i]);

  $('table').append(tRow.append(tCell));
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n7cyE/93/

Comment: Is there a particular setting that's needed to get this to work outside of jsFiddle? Trying this in a blank js file returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined"

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loaded?

Comment: I would change the line to not use HTML and instead use TEXT (since in this example we're only inserting text into the table cell)

tCell = $('<td>').text(data[i]);

Answer (score 4):

To add multiple columns and rows, we can also do a string concatenation. Not the best way, but it sure works.

```
             var resultstring='<table>';
      for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
              //array arr contains the field names in this case
          resultstring+= '<th>'+ arr[j] + '</th>';
      }
      $(resultset).each(function(i, result) {
          // resultset is in json format
          resultstring+='<tr>';
          for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
              resultstring+='<td>'+ result[arr[j]]+ '</td>';
          }
          resultstring+='</tr>';
      });
      resultstring+='</table>';
          $('#resultdisplay').html(resultstring);
```

This also allows you to add rows and columns to the table dynamically, without hardcoding the fieldnames.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you can do: http://jsfiddle.net/n7cyE/4/

```
$('#here_table').append('<table></table>');
var table = $('#here_table').children();
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    table.append( '<tr><td>' + 'result' +  i + '</td></tr>' );
}
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

Following is done for multiple file uploads using jquery:

**File input button:**

```
<div>
 <input type="file" name="uploadFiles" id="uploadFiles" multiple="multiple" class="input-xlarge" onchange="getFileSizeandName(this);"/> 
</div>
```

**Displaying File name and File size in a table:**

```
<div id="uploadMultipleFilediv">
<table id="uploadTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"></table></div>
```

**Javascript for getting the file name and file size:**

```
function getFileSizeandName(input)
{
    var select = $('#uploadTable');
    //select.empty();
    var totalsizeOfUploadFiles = "";
    for(var i =0; i<input.files.length; i++)
    {
        var filesizeInBytes = input.files[i].size; // file size in bytes
        var filesizeInMB = (filesizeInBytes / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2); // convert the file size from bytes to mb
        var filename = input.files[i].name;
        select.append($('<tr><td>'+filename+'</td><td>'+filesizeInMB+'</td></tr>'));
        totalsizeOfUploadFiles = totalsizeOfUploadFiles+filesizeInMB;
        //alert("File name is : "+filename+" || size : "+filesizeInMB+" MB || size : "+filesizeInBytes+" Bytes");               
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or static HTML without the loop for creating some links (or whatever). Place the `<div id="menu">` on any page to reproduce the HTML.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>HTML Masterpage</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function nav() {
                var menuHTML= '<ul><li><a href="#">link 1</a></li></ul><ul><li><a href="#">link 2</a></li></ul>';
                $('#menu').append(menuHTML);
            }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="nav()">
        <div id="menu"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote rather good function that can generate vertical and horizontal tables:

```
function generateTable(rowsData, titles, type, _class) {
    var $table = $("<table>").addClass(_class);
    var $tbody = $("<tbody>").appendTo($table);


    if (type == 2) {//vertical table
        if (rowsData.length !== titles.length) {
            console.error('rows and data rows count doesent match');
            return false;
        }
        titles.forEach(function (title, index) {
            var $tr = $("<tr>");
            $("<th>").html(title).appendTo($tr);
            var rows = rowsData[index];
            rows.forEach(function (html) {
                $("<td>").html(html).appendTo($tr);
            });
            $tr.appendTo($tbody);
        });

    } else if (type == 1) {//horsantal table 
        var valid = true;
        rowsData.forEach(function (row) {
            if (!row) {
                valid = false;
                return;
            }

            if (row.length !== titles.length) {
                valid = false;
                return;
            }
        });

        if (!valid) {
            console.error('rows and data rows count doesent match');
            return false;
        }

        var $tr = $("<tr>");
        titles.forEach(function (title, index) {
            $("<th>").html(title).appendTo($tr);
        });
        $tr.appendTo($tbody);

        rowsData.forEach(function (row, index) {
            var $tr = $("<tr>");
            row.forEach(function (html) {
                $("<td>").html(html).appendTo($tr);
            });
            $tr.appendTo($tbody);
        });
    }

    return $table;
}
```

usage example:

```
var title = [
    'مساحت موجود',
    'مساحت باقیمانده',
    'مساحت در طرح'
];

var rows = [
    [number_format(data.source.area,2)],
    [number_format(data.intersection.area,2)],
    [number_format(data.deference.area,2)]
];

var $ft = generateTable(rows, title, 2,"table table-striped table-hover table-bordered");

$ft.appendTo( GroupAnalyse.$results );

var title = [
    'جهت',
    'اندازه قبلی',
    'اندازه فعلی',
    'وضعیت',
    'میزان عقب نشینی',
];

var rows = data.edgesData.map(function (r) {
    return [
        r.directionText,
        r.lineLength,
        r.newLineLength,
        r.stateText,
        r.lineLengthDifference
    ];
});


var $et = generateTable(rows, title, 1,"table table-striped table-hover table-bordered");

$et.appendTo( GroupAnalyse.$results );

$('<hr/>').appendTo( GroupAnalyse.$results );
```

example result:

[image: example result]

Answer (score 1):

A working example using the method mentioned above and using JSON to represent the data. This is used in my project of dealing with ajax calls fetching data from server.

http://jsfiddle.net/vinocui/22mX6/1/

In your html:
        < table id='here_table' >< /table >

JS code:

```
function feed_table(tableobj){
    // data is a JSON object with
    //{'id': 'table id',
    // 'header':[{'a': 'Asset Tpe', 'b' : 'Description', 'c' : 'Assets Value', 'd':'Action'}], 
    // 'data': [{'a': 'Non Real Estate',  'b' :'Credit card',  'c' :'$5000' , 'd': 'Edit/Delete' },...   ]}

    $('#' + tableobj.id).html( '' );

    $.each([tableobj.header, tableobj.data], function(_index, _obj){
    $.each(_obj, function(index, row){
        var line = "";
        $.each(row, function(key, value){
            if(0 === _index){
                line += '<th>' + value + '</th>';    
            }else{
                line += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
            }
        });
        line = '<tr>' + line + '</tr>';
        $('#' + tableobj.id).append(line);
    });


    });    
}

// testing
$(function(){
    var t = {
    'id': 'here_table',
    'header':[{'a': 'Asset Tpe', 'b' : 'Description', 'c' : 'Assets Value', 'd':'Action'}], 
    'data': [{'a': 'Non Real Estate',  'b' :'Credit card',  'c' :'$5000' , 'd': 'Edit/Delete' },
         {'a': 'Real Estate',  'b' :'Property',  'c' :'$500000' , 'd': 'Edit/Delete' }
        ]};

    feed_table(t);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As for me, this approach is prettier:

```
String.prototype.embraceWith = function(tag) {
    return "<" + tag + ">" + this + "</" + tag + ">";
};

var results = [
  {type:"Fiat", model:500, color:"white"}, 
  {type:"Mercedes", model: "Benz", color:"black"},
  {type:"BMV", model: "X6", color:"black"}
];

var tableHeader = ("Type".embraceWith("th") + "Model".embraceWith("th") + "Color".embraceWith("th")).embraceWith("tr");
var tableBody = results.map(function(item) {
    return (item.type.embraceWith("td") + item.model.toString().embraceWith("td") + item.color.embraceWith("td")).embraceWith("tr")
}).join("");

var table = (tableHeader + tableBody).embraceWith("table");

$("#result-holder").append(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

i prefer the most readable and extensible way using jquery.
Also, you can build fully dynamic content on the fly.
Since jquery version 1.4 you can pass attributes to elements which is, 
imho, a killer feature.
Also the code can be kept cleaner.

```
$(function(){

        var tablerows = new Array();

        $.each(['result1', 'result2', 'result3'], function( index, value ) {
            tablerows.push('<tr><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
        });

        var table =  $('<table/>', {
           html:  tablerows
       });

        var div = $('<div/>', {
            id: 'here_table',
            html: table
        });

        $('body').append(div);

    });
```

Addon: passing more than one "html" tag you've to use array notation like:
e.g.

```
var div = $('<div/>', {
            id: 'here_table',
            html: [ div1, div2, table ]
        });
```

best Rgds.
Franz

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="game_table" border="1">
```

and Jquery

```
var i;
for (i = 0; ii < 10; i++) 
{

        var tr = $("<tr></tr>")
        var ii;
        for (ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) 
        {
        tr.append(`<th>Firstname</th>`)
        }

$('#game_table').append(tr)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The question you have been writing this answer for is very old (6 years) and has already been answered extensively by other users. You can see the age of a question above the author box. Maybe you want to support users with ongoing unanswered questions using your awesome knowledge today! You can find the newest questions by typing the tag name into the searchbar and you will only see the questions for the technology you want to answer questions for. For jQuery you can find this page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

Answer (score 0):

this is most better

html

```
<div id="here_table"> </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#here_table').append( '<table>' );

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
$('#here_table').append( '<tr>' + 'result' +  i + '</tr>' );

    for(ii=0;ii<3;ii++)
    {
    $('#here_table').append( '<td>' + 'result' +  i + '</tr>' );
    }
}

$('#here_table').append(  '</table>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that you could use Emmet to achieve the same result. First, check what Emmet can do for you at https://emmet.io/

In a nutshell, with Emmet, you can expand a string into a complexe HTML markup as shown in the examples below:

Example #1

```emmet
ul>li*5
```

... will produce

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Example #2

```emmet
div#header+div.page+div#footer.class1.class2.class3
```

... will produce

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div class="page"></div>
<div id="footer" class="class1 class2 class3"></div>
```

And list goes on. There are more examples at https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/

And there is a library for doing that using jQuery. It's called Emmet.js and available at https://github.com/christiansandor/Emmet.js

Answer (score 0):

Here the below code helps to generate responsive html table

#javascript

```
(function($){
var data = [{
    "head 1": "row1 col 1",
    "head 2": "row1 col 2",
    "head 3": "row1 col 3"
}, {
    "head 1": "row2 col 1",
    "head 2": "row2 col 2",
    "head 3": "row2 col 3"
}, {
    "head 1": "row3 col 1",
    "head 2": "row3 col 2",
    "head 3": "row3 col 3"
}];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var accordianhtml = "<button class='accordion'>" + data[i][small_screen_heading] + "<span class='arrow rarrow'>&#8594;</span><span class='arrow darrow'>&#8595;</span></button><div class='panel'><p><table class='accordian_table'>";
    var table_row = null;
    var table_header = null;
    for (var key in data[i]) {
        accordianhtml = accordianhtml + "<tr><th>" + key + "</th><td>" + data[i][key] + "</td></tr>";
        if (i === 0 && true) {
            table_header = table_header + "<th>" + key + "</th>";
        }
        table_row = table_row + "<td>" + data[i][key] + "</td>"
    }
    if (i === 0 && true) {
        table_header = "<tr>" + table_header + "</tr>";
        $(".mv_table #simple_table").append(table_header);
    }
    table_row = "<tr>" + table_row + "</tr>";
    $(".mv_table #simple_table").append(table_row);
    accordianhtml = accordianhtml + "</table></p></div>";
    $(".mv_table .accordian_content").append(accordianhtml);
}
}(jquery)
```

Here we can see the demo [responsive html table generator](https://www.htmlcodegenerator-tools.com/2019/11/html-responsive-table-generator-blogger-mobile.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    let html = '';
    html += '<table class="tblWay" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">';
    html += '<tbody>';
    html += '<tr style="background-color:#EEEFF0">';
    html += '<td width="80"> </td>';
    html += '<td><b>Shipping Method</b></td>';
    html += '<td><b>Shipping Cost</b></td>';
    html += '<td><b>Transit Time</b></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    html += '</tbody>';
    html += '</table>';
    $('.product-shipping-more').append(html);
```