# How to construct a complete HTML table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to construct a complete table using jQuery.

I try to learn or copycat from this question

[Create table with jQuery - append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749236/create-table-with-jquery-append)

but no luck.

What I want to create is

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>                                  
         <th>Problem 5</th>
         <th>Problem 6</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The jQuery code I created is

```
var $table = $('<table/>');

var $thead = $('<thead/>');
$thead.append('<tr>' + '<th>Problem 5</th>' + '<th>Problem 6</th>' + '</tr>';
$table.append(thead);

var $tbody = $('<tbody/>');
$tbody.append( '<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>' );
$table.append(tbody);

$('#GroupTable').append($table);
```

But it failed running.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: @jason yes, I have everything, I will edit with some more information.

Comment: the single most important thing you can do right now is learn how to check the error console in a web browser, so that you can help yourself in the future by checking for error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a right paren in your `$thead` declaration:

```
$thead.append('<tr>' + '<th>Problem 5</th>' + '<th>Problem 6</th>' + '</tr>'); 
                                                                            ^
```

and you aren't appending your variables correctly:

```
$table.append($thead);
              ^

$table.append($tbody);
              ^
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/eYS4v/).

Comment: actually, he is missing more than that. http://jsfiddle.net/77uLd/ Here it is working

Comment: paren is parenthesis. You should check your syntax before assuming you are doing something wrong. usually ctrl+shift+j will show all syntax errors as they are found (in chrome at least)

Answer (score 0):

thead, tbody is undefined? $thead, $tbody?

```
$table.append(thead);
```

and

```
$table.append(tbody);
```