# For loop Jquery creating table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have been trying to create a table dynamically based on an array return from another function.

I have 2 array :

```
var listOfNames = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var scoreLabels = ['Query', 'Entry', '% Matched', 'Alignment Len', 'Mismatches', 'Gaps', 'E-Value', 'Bitscore'];
```

The first array will contain element which will be id of each row.

The second array is the list of columns for each row.

My html looks like this

```
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

and the for loop that I have written looks like this :

```
for (var i = 0; listOfNames.length < i; i++) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>');
  $(row).attr('id', listOfNames[i]);

  for (var x = 0; scoreLabels.length < x; x++) {
      var tableHeader = $('<td></td>');
      $(tableHeader).attr('text', scoreLabels[x]);
      $(tableHeader).appendTo(row);      
  } 
$(row).appendTo('table');
}
```

I have been looking at other posts that teaches the creation of table dynamically with jquery, but to no avail.

Please kindly advice and let me know where i went wrong .

The js fiddle can be found here

http://jsfiddle.net/t16scofy/2

Comment: `for (var i = 0; listOfNames.length < i; i++)` <-- Are you sure about your stop condition there?

Comment: You fiddle has a typo `for (var i = 0; listOfNames.lenth < i; i++)`

Comment: Another typo: `.appendTo('tabl')`

Comment: `row` is already a jQuery collection, theres no need to wrap it again. Also, you spelt `table` incorrectly in your `appendTo()` method, so nothing happens with `row`

Comment: sorry typo has been fixed but still doesnt work... was smashing my head on the keyboard for the past hour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create table with jQuery - append](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749236/create-table-with-jquery-append)

Comment: Your `for loop` conditions don't look right to me. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/t16scofy/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For-loops...

Just read your for-loops out loud:

```
for (var i = 0; listOfNames.length < i; i++) {...}
```

becomes:

> for i - starting at 0 - do ... as long as the length of listOfNames is smaller then i.

I starts at 0. and the length of listOfNames is always larger then 0. It is never smaller. so this for loop will never do `...`

Same goes for you inner for-loop

### corrected:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listOfNames.length; i++) {...}
```

or if you really want the i after the .length:

```
for (var i = 0; listOfNames.length > i; i++) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few typos and wrong conditions in both your `for loops`.

This should do it:

```
var listOfNames = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var scoreLabels = ['Query', 'Entry', '% Matched', 'Alignment Len', 'Mismatches', 'Gaps', 'E-Value', 'Bitscore'];

// If i starts with 0, and you're incrementing it, you obviously want the loop 
// to go until it reaches a bigger value, not the other way round.
for (var i = 0; i < listOfNames.length; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr>', { class: i.toString() });

    // If x starts with 0, and you're incrementing it, you obviously want the loop 
    // to go until it reaches a bigger value, not the other way round.
    for (var x = 0; x < scoreLabels.length; x++) {
        var tableHeader = $('<td>', { text: scoreLabels[x] });

        tableHeader.appendTo(row);
    }

    row.appendTo('table');
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/t16scofy/5/)