# Insert row with different colspan into table

Tags: javascript, c#, html-table

I have a table where I want to insert a new row with a different colspan then the original table. Here is part of my code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("eTable");    
var rowIndex = document.getElementById(ID).rowIndex;
var row = table.insertRow(rowIndex + 1);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
```

My original table has 5 columns, but I want to merge cell1,cell2, and cell3. How do I do that?

Comment: "_row with a different colspan_" There's no such a thing in HTMLTables, `rowspan` and `colspan` are properties of `td` elements. But you can merge the cells. Add `cell.colspan = 3;` and omit `cell3` and `cell4`.

Comment: how would you do that ?

Comment: ??How?? Exactly like in my comment ...

Comment: @TheAsker build table using string like `var tableBuild = '<table>` //loop your data here as required with col or rowspan` </table>'` .   Refer this solution  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749347/4425004

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to set the colspan for a column and skip some other columns. Based on your code (added second row):

```js
var table = document.getElementById("eTable");    
var rowIndex = document.getElementById("ID").rowIndex;
var row = table.insertRow(rowIndex + 1);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
row = table.insertRow(rowIndex);
cell = row.insertCell(0);
cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.colSpan = "3";
cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
```

```css
table { border: 1px solid #000; width: 100%; }
table tr { }
table td { border: 1px solid red; height: 20px;}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="ID" value=0 />
<table id="eTable">
</table>
```

Run the snippet or if you prefer, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftqLkmvn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below javascript code.

```
var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
cell2.id = "myTd";
document.getElementById("myTd").colSpan = "3"
```